# WCF Upload File - ideas & Examples

Tags: c#, wcf

Im currently working on a win forms project, 
Im looking to offer a Online Backup service that will allow the client to transfer their database onto our server(s).

So Ive got a method that already creates a backup of the SQL database, then zips and encrypts.
Ive got a wcf end point setup, I just need the bit where I say take this File (FileStream?) and upload it via this service and save in this folder.

Ive looked at some of the other other example on stackoverflow but, I just cant seem to make head nor tail.

So im really looking for a decent example\link (step by step) that will help me with this, also the file could be potentially big (max of 2GB) so i need to ensure I dont get any time outs on the connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer, for the WCF part, you will have to use [Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx).

For storing the file, yes, FileStream on Sql Server is a good idea since the files will be parts of sql maintenance process, especially backups and transactions.

To upload the file, you could also simply use an Http Put request, aside the WCF service.